# Exporting scheduled jobs in Oracle

Tags: oracle, export, jobs

This is probably very simple but i already exported all but the scheduled jobs i created to subsequent schemas.

How can I create a sql script of the scheduled jobs I created in Oracle? I know in SQL developer, you can use the Database Export wizard to export DDLs and data but you can't use it to export prior scheduled jobs.

I am trying not to have to recreate all my jobs for each environment as I go. Can you please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we are talking about `dbms_scheduler` jobs (rather than, say, jobs scheduled using the `dbms_job` package), you can use the `dbms_metadata` package to generate the DDL. Specifically, the [`dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414).  Something like

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'PROCOBJ', <<job name>>, <<schema>> )
  FROM dual
```

should work, for example.

Here is a [list of the object types that `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` supports](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BGBIEDIA).

Here is an example of [using the `PROCOBJ` trick to get `dbms_metadata` to script out a job](http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/oracle-getting-the-ddl-for-scheduler-jobs/).

Comment: even now, dbms_metadata does not support dbms_scheduler jobs. The JOBs mentioned in the list are the dbms_job type of jobs.

Comment: @ik_zelf - D'oh, you're right.  Updated my answer to use the old `PROCOBJ` trick.  I thought that was no longer necessary but apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: hey, nice trick, I did not know that.

Comment: Thanks!! You just save me hours trying to replicate job creation manually ;)